# Get better accuracy with Region Monitoring and location in general

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm using didStartMonitoringForRegion, didEnterRegion, didExitRegion to to check if a user entered  \ exited a location. That works great if I'll want my app to be notified when a user entered a shopping mall for example.

I'm looking for a creative way to notify my app when a user is close to a specific store inside a building. Because GPS won't help me much here I thought about checking if that store WiFi SSID is available on the iPhone SSID list but after some reading I learned that I'll need to use private API to accomplish that so that's off the list.

I understand that there isn't an API for that but maybe someone can give me an idea

Thanks

Comment: A specific mall? Can you put BTLE beacons in there?

Comment: I have no idea what BLE beacons are but I'll research on that. In genera I can put any hardware I want in those stores so those kind of ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Blue Tooth Low Energy, plenty of info on google. iPhone 4S and above can scan for the beacons.

Comment: Search for ibeacons, new in ios 7 uses BTLE.

Comment: Thanks. The app suppose to support iOS 6. I've read that it's still possible with iOS 6 to get a list of BLE around you and search for a familiar name (which will suffice). Is that correct?